# Grails 2.5.0: way to fill database automatically

Tags: grails, spring-batch

I have a business web application made with **Grails 2.5.0**.
In this application, I use a GSP form to upload files and to fill a database.
In fact, I upload httpd conf files from a directory and I extract informations from them.

Now, I want to find a solution to do the same automatically. But I didn't find solution.

I tried Spring Batch plugin but it does work with **Grails 2.5.0**.Other Batch plugin seems too old to work.
Other way, it perhaps to import files at startup but I don't know if you can read files from a directory at startup ( *e.g : from /var/myapp/conf* ).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something when the application starts add it to `BootStrap.groovy`

Comment: But in Bootstrap.groovy, can you load files that are in any directory ?.For example, if you have a directory not in web applications classpath directories (

Comment: I would guess you should be able to read any file as long as you have permissions(e.g. the tomcat user should have access to the file).